# My computer force closes games while I’m playing them

Tags: power-electronics, feedback, cpu, motherboard, corrosion

I have done everything I can think of to solve this problem. My computer sat in my car for months while I was in boot camp and I found a spot on there that might be causing it but I don’t know enough about boards to tell. Can some one help?
Motherboard is tuf gaming x570 Wi-Fi

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get better pictures? Both a lower zoom one showing the larger area and a clearer one of that white area.

Comment: Yes one sec I’ll take a new picture

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol and a preferably carbon fiber toothbrush, a scrub and a picture after would tell if that’s an issue.

Answer (score 4):

That's corrosion, probably from getting damp, but it's around the TPM header you aren't even using so probably not your issue. It's possible there's damage elsewhere on the board though if one area corroded. Where you would be concerned about is around the CPU socket if you're having crashes under load.

I would also try to narrow down the cause of the instability. Can you pass a CPU-only stress test like a few hours of prime95? A ram test like memtest? Or a GPU-only stress test? That will give you an idea what is broken.

Comment: How does this answer the question, which does not seem well-defined to begin with. There's more questions than answers, maybe this should be a comment?

Comment: I interpreted the question to be "is this area of damage the cause of my problems". I think the answer is no and gave suggestions to further investigate or rule it out.

Comment: Thank you I will try those